# How can I enable two buttons clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the jQuery plugin called "**sidr**" (http://www.berriart.com/sidr/)

This plugin enables implementation of side menu.

With these code below, only the 1st button is clickable and working fine.
However, I want to enable both of these buttons to open side menu.

How can I modify my code?

**Menu Part**

```
<div id="sidr">
...Menu Contents here...
</div>
```

**1st button**

```
<a href="#sidr" id="menu" class="focus_button right">Menu</a>
```

**2nd button**

```
<a id="menu" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="#sidr">Menu</a>
```

Comment: That isn't valid HTML. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2 The `id` attribute "must be unique in a document."

Comment: Where's the javascript? We can't tell you how to modify your code if we can't see your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the id twice, and jQuery only recorgnices the first id:

```
<a id="menu" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="#sidr">Menu</a>
```

you need to define another id to open the menu with both buttons

**edit:**

you could use the `jQuery.sidr()` Function to open the menus by yourself:

Comment: Where am I supposed to define another id at? Even if I give another id to 2nd one, it didn't open the side menu:(

Comment: Can I insert `jQuery.sidr()` into the link somehow?

Comment: are you looking for the `onclick=""` attribute?